# Pass a data.frame with column names and fields as filter

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following:

```
filt = data.frame(X1 = c("Gender","EmployeeStatus"),X2 = c('Male','Active'))
df = data.frame(Gender = c('Male','F','Male','Male','F'),EmployeeStatus = c('Active','na','Active','Active','na'))
```

I want to be able to use the data in `filt` as a filter for df. I've tried below but i'm getting an Error in get: invalid first argument.

```
 d2 = df[get(filt[1,1])==filt[2,1] &
                  get(filt[1,2])==filt[2,2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `base R` to do this

```
df[Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, df[as.character(filt$X1)], 
            as.character(filt$X2))),]
#   Gender EmployeeStatus
#1   Male         Active
#3   Male         Active
#4   Male         Active
```

Or with `rowSums` from `base R`

```
df[rowSums(df[as.character(filt$X1)] == as.list(as.character(filt$X2))) == 2,]
```

Comment: I like this approach too!

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called a `semi_join` and you need the filter data frame to be in a different format:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Gender = c('Male','F','Male','Male','F'),EmployeeStatus = c('Active','na','Active','Active','na'),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
filt <- data.frame(Gender = "Male",EmployeeStatus = "Active",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> semi_join(df,filt)
Joining, by = c("Gender", "EmployeeStatus")
  Gender EmployeeStatus
1   Male         Active
2   Male         Active
3   Male         Active
```

(By the way, I think you transposed some indices in your question.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many problem in code by `OP`. The syntax is valid only in scope of `data.table` like:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

d2 = df[get(as.character(filt[1,1]))==as.character(filt[1,2]) &
          get(as.character(filt[2,1]))==as.character(filt[2,2])]

#     Gender EmployeeStatus
# 1:   Male         Active
# 2:   Male         Active
# 3:   Male         Active
```

Let me try to explain the reason why `OP` code is not working.

```
get(filt[1,1]) => Gender.
```

As we all know, `df[Gender,]` or `df["Gender",]` doesn't work in scope of a `data.frame`. The variable `Gender` is not available in scope of `data.frame`. Above all type of `filt[1,1]` is `factor` which cannot be coerced by `get`.

Hence, the changes which have been implemented in above solution can be described as:

First, `as.character(filt[1,1])` will change `factor` to `character`. Then `df[get("Gender"),]` is valid syntax in scope for `data.table`.