# Logic parsing in R

Tags: r

Building off of this question [Pass a data.frame with column names and fields as filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826639/pass-a-data-frame-with-column-names-and-fields-as-filter)

Let's say we have the following data set:

```
filt = data.table(X1 = c("Gender","Male"),
                  X2 = c('jobFamilyGroup','Finance'),
                  X3 = c('jobFamilyGroup','Software Dev')
df = data.table(Gender = c('Male','F','Male','Male','F'),
                EmployeeStatus = c('Active','na','Active','Active','na'),
                jobFamilyGroup = c('Finance','Software Dev','HR','Finance','Software Dev'))
```

and I want to use `filt` as a filter for `df`. `filt` is done by grabbing an input from Shiny and transforming it a bit to get me that data.table above. My goal is to filter df so we have: `All rows that are MALE AND (Software Dev OR Finance)`.

Currently, I'm hardcoding it to always be an AND but that isn't ideal for situations like this. My thought would be to have multiple `if` conditions to catch things like this, but I feel like there could be an easier approach for building this logic in.

___________UPDATE______________

Once I have a table like `filt` I can pass code like:

```
 if(!is.null(primary))
      {
      if(ncol(primary)==1){
        d2 = df[get(as.character(primary[1,1]))==as.character(primary[2,1])]

      }
      else if(length(primary)==2){
        d2 = df[get(as.character(primary[1,1]))==as.character(primary[2,1]) &
                  get(as.character(primary[1,2]))==as.character(primary[2,2])]
      }

      else{
        d2 = df[get(as.character(primary[1,1]))==as.character(primary[1,2]) &
                  get(as.character(primary[1,2]))==as.character(primary[2,2]) &
                  get(as.character(primary[1,3]))==as.character(primary[2,3])]
      }
      }
```

But this code doesn't account for the OR Logical needed if there are multiple inputs for one type of grouping. Meaning the current code says give me all rows where: `Gender == Male & Job Family Group == 'Finance'& Job Family Group == 'Software Dev'` When really it should be `Gender == Male & (Job Family Group == 'Finance'| Job Family Group == 'Software Dev')`

this is a minimal example meaning there are many other columns so ideally the solution has the ability to determine when a multiple input for a grouping is present.

Comment: Where is your current code? Exactly what types of conditions are you trying to account for? This question doesn't seem specific enough to be answerable.

Comment: I'll add some elements to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your problem, what if you parsed it so your logic looked like:

```
Gender %in% c("Male") & jobFamilyGroup %in% c('Finance','Software Dev')
```

By lumping all filter values with the same column name together in an `%in%` you get your OR and you keep your AND between column names.

**UPDATE**

Consider the case discussed in comments below.

Your reactive inputs a data.table specifying

- Gender IS Male
- Country IS China OR US
- EmployeeStatus IS Active

In the sample data you provided there is no country column, so I added one. I extract the columns to be filtered and the values to be filtered and `split` the values to be filtered by the columns. I pass this into an `lapply` which does the logical check for each column using an `%in%` rather than a `==` so that options within the same column are treated as an `|` instead of a `&`. Then I `rbind` the logical results together and `apply` an `all` to the columns and then filter `df` by the results.

This approach handles the `&` between columns and the `|` within columns. It supports any number of columns to be searched removing the need for your if/else logic.

```
library(data.table)

df = data.table(Gender = c('Male','F','Male','Male','F'),
                EmployeeStatus = c('Active','na','Active','Active','na'),
                jobFamilyGroup = c('Finance','Software Dev','HR','Finance','Software Dev'),
                Country = c('China','China','US','US','China'))
filt = data.table(x1 = c('Gender' , 'Male'),x2 = c('Country' , 'China'),x3 = c('Country','US'), x4 = c('EmployeeStatus','Active'))
column = unlist(filt[1,])
value = unlist(filt[2,])
tofilter = split(value,column)
tokeep = apply(do.call(rbind,lapply(names(tofilter),function(x){
  `[[`(df,x) %in% tofilter[[x]]
})),2,all)
df[tokeep==TRUE]

#>       Gender EmployeeStatus jobFamilyGroup Country
#>    1:   Male         Active        Finance   China
#>    2:   Male         Active             HR      US
#>    3:   Male         Active        Finance      US
```

Comment: This is a nice easy approach, but not sure it's robust enough for my solution. Let's say the duplicate grouping is a different column, say `country`. The input changes based on the user selection of the filter.

Comment: Why would country not work? or anything else? Say `split(unlist(filt[2,]),unlist(filt[1,]))` to make a list of all grouped values. Then your code should work similarly just replacing `==` with `%in%`

Comment: `filt` is a `reactive` element in my shiny app. So let's say filt looked like: `filt = data.table(x1 = c('Gender' , 'Male'),x2 = c('Country' , 'China'),x3 = c('Country','US'), x4 = c('Status','Active'))` This is sayings `Males from China OR US that are active (vs though who are inactive)

Comment: I expanded my answer @TedMosby to show how my solution works. I added a Country column to your example data and used the filt you specified here.  Note how it handles all three conditions and the logic you specified.

Comment: Wow, your answer is beautiful! That's exactly what I was trying to do